# Sorting Tables With JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a JQuery plugin that will let me manually resort rows in a table with drag-n-drop.  I found something in JQuery that does what I want for unordered lists (http://jqueryui.it/demos/sortable).  If you know of a similar solution for tables, please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I searched around some more for an example of applying the JQuery UI's Sortable to a table and found one at http://setiabud.blogspot.com/2009/06/jquery-ui-sortable-with-table.html.  Basically, it works exactly the same way for tables as it does for lists.  The only thing I had to add to my table was a `<tbody>` tag:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortableTable tbody.sortableContent").sortable( {placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"});
        $( "#sortableImageTable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>

<table id="sortableTable" ...>
    <tbody class="sortableContent">
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
        .
        .
        .
```

Thanks for all your suggestions and input.